# Execute an action if your account does not login within 'X' number of days (OSX)

Tags: macos, launchd

So, I'm trying to write a script that can perform an action if I am unable to login to my computer with X number of days. An example of this would be to send an email if I don't login after a week. This is mainly for fun, but I want to have some kind of insurance (ie "if you kill me bad guy incriminating docs will be emailed to the FBI).

My two questions are

a) what does a code like this look like

b) do I inject this into the kernel or is it more of a daemon

Comment: If your computer is switched off, then it can't do anything. Or is it if your computer is running but you just aren't logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'at' utility.  You can have a 'logout' action start the 'at' script and a 'login' action cancel it.

Comment: Could you be more detailed. Is the 'at' script command line, framework, or is this something else?

Comment: @November it's a command line interface for the launchd daemon (on OSX). Try the manpage: `man 1 at`